# Bootstrap Button and input box , side by side

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Can anybody please advise/correct me how to align or arrange the button and input box side by side without grouping in bootstrap.

I had searched few examples in the internet which are only in grouping of elements.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/erama035/p9dagmL3/3/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

       <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
            <button class="btn btn-default col-sm-2 col-md-2">add</button>
            <input  class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-2"/>
       </div>

       <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7">
            <button class="btn btn-default col-md-2">remove</button>
            <input  class="form-control col-md-5"/>
       </div>

   </div>  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick way would be, to simply use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FTutorials%2FUsing_CSS_flexible_boxes) for the parent `<div>`. This converts the child elements to flex items, which are arranged side by side by default.

```
.container > .row > div {
  display: flex;
}
```

The proper way would be to use Bootstraps predefined classes for grouping.

```css
.container>.row>div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
      <button class="btn btn-default">add</button>
      <input class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7">
      <button class="btn btn-default">remove</button>
      <input class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for late reply , i really appreciate your answer this really helps me.  but i doesn't want to change the css , because it might effect the entire project , so is there any way that can only effect this particular block..

Comment: Sure, just give your block a custom CSS class and apply the styles to that class.

Answer (score 0):

for the cross-browser you can simple use inline-block

```
.btn,.form-control{display: inline-block; width: auto;}
```